# Orienteering map game using C++

Tags: c++

I solved a programming puzzle using a brute force method and without dynamic programming, and it worked fine.  Here is the puzzle:

> An orienteering map is to be given in the following format.
>
> ```
> " ##### "
> " #...# "
> " #S#G# "
> " ##### "
> ```
>
> Calculate the minimum distance from the start to the goal with passing all the checkpoints.
>
> - A map consists of 5 characters as following. You can assume that the map does not contain any invalid characters and the map has exactly one start symbol 'S' and exactly one goal symbol 'G'.
> - 'S' means the orienteering start.
> - 'G' means the orienteering goal.
> - '@' means an orienteering checkpoint.
> - '.' means an opened-block that players can pass.
> - '#' means a closed-block that players cannot pass.
> - It is allowed to move only by one step vertically or horizontally (up, down, left, or right) to the next block. Other types of movements, such as moving diagonally (left up, right up, left down and right down) and skipping one or more blocks, are NOT permitted.
> - You MUST NOT get out of the map.
> - Distance is to be defined as the number of movements to the different blocks.
> - You CAN pass opened-blocks, checkpoints, the start, and the goal more than once if necessary.
> - You can assume that parameters satisfy following conditions.
> - 1 <= width <= 100
> - 1 <= height <= 100
>     The maximum number of checkpoints is 18.

Then I found a much faster solution, which I don't understand some things about:

```
#include<iostream>  
#include<algorithm>  
#include<cstdio>  
#include<vector>  
#include<cstring>  
#include<map>  
#include<queue>  
#include<stack>  
#include<string>  
#include<cstdlib>  
#include<ctime>  
#include<set>  
#include<math.h>  
using namespace std;  
typedef long long LL;  
const int maxn = 1e2+ 10;  
#define rep(i,a,b) for(int i=(a);i<=(b);i++)  
#define pb push_back  
std::vector<int>path;  
const int INF=1<<20;  
struct Point  
{  
 int x,y;  
 bool operator < (const Point &a)const  
 {  
   return x<a.x||(x==a.x)&&y<a.y;  
 }  
};  
std::vector<Point>P;  
char mat[maxn][maxn];  
int vis[maxn][maxn];  
int w,h,s,e;  
int d[1<<20][20];  
int dx[]={-1,0,0,1};  
int dy[]={0,-1,1,0};  
int dist[25][25];  
int main(){  
ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);  
cin.tie(0);  
while(cin>>w>>h){  
map<Point,int>id;  
P.clear();  
path.clear();  
memset(d,100,sizeof d);  
memset(dist,100,sizeof dist);  
for(int i=0;i<h;i++){  
    scanf("%s",mat[i]);  
    for(int j=0;mat[i][j];++j){  
        char &c=mat[i][j];  
        if(c=='S'||c=='G'||c=='@'){  
            P.pb((Point){i,j});  
            int sz=P.size();  
            id[P[sz-1]]=sz;  
            if(c=='S')s=sz-1;  
            else if(c=='G')e=sz-1;  
            path.pb(sz-1);  
        }  
    }  
}  

for(int i=0;i<path.size();i++){  
    Point now=P[path[i]];  
    int x=path[i];  
    //out<<"x "<<x<<endl;  
    dist[x][x]=0;  
    memset(vis,0,sizeof vis);  
    vis[now.x][now.y]=1;  
    queue<Point>q;  
    q.push(now);  
    //cout<<"Bfs"<<endl;  
    while(!q.empty()){  
        now=q.front();q.pop();  
        for(int i=0;i<4;i++){  
            int nx=now.x+dx[i],ny=now.y+dy[i];  
            if(nx>=0&&nx<h&&ny>=0&&ny<w&&mat[nx][ny]!='#'&&!vis[nx][ny]){  
                Point tp=(Point){nx,ny};  
                q.push(tp);  
                vis[nx][ny]=vis[now.x][now.y]+1;  
                if(id[tp]){  
                    dist[x][id[tp]-1]=vis[now.x][now.y];    
                }  
            }  

        }  

    }  

}  

d[1<<s][s]=0;  
int M=path.size();  
for(int i=0;i<(1<<M);++i){  
    for(int j=0;j<M;j++){  
        int p=path[j];  
        for(int k=0;1<<k<=i;k++){  
            if(i&(1<<k)){  
                d[i|(1<<p)][p]=min(d[i|(1<<p)][p],d[i][k]+dist[k][p]);  
            }  
        }  
    }  
}  

cout<<d[(1<<M)-1][e]<<endl;  

}  
return 0;  
}
```

Here are 3 specific questions I have about it:

1. What is the use of the constant `INF`? It isn’t used anywhere in the program. I understand that programmers very often leave some things in their programs which may not seem to be of any use presently, but would be useful for any future modifications. Does INF serve that same purpose? If any kind of modification is performed to make the program more efficient or to use a different method, `INF` is used?
2. The use of the left-shift operator inside the array dimensions. For example, `int d[1<<20][20]`. What purpose does the let-shift operator accomplish with regard to this program? There are various other instances where the let shift operator has been used inside array dimensions, and I can’t understand why.
3. The overloading of the less-than operator. In the `Point` structure, the less-than operator is overloaded. But I can't seem to find out where in the program it has been called. It needs a Point object to call it, but I can’t find any place where any Point object calls that member function.

Comment: wow. such indentation. so whitespace. very no empty lines. wow!

Comment: why ask same exact question? Clearly nobody wants to answer or just doesn't want to waste time and effort on answering this question.

Comment: I gave you a +1 for you trying to come back with specificity...that is good.  But there are some ropes to learn in question-asking here before you can ask really good ones.  Hopefully my feedback will help, and I do encourage you to continue trying to work at it.  You'll get the hang of it eventually.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

Your questions aren't invalid, but do not need all the context to ask them.  They could each be separate questions, and *I've provided a link for each showing that the essence of the question has been asked before more succinctly*.  If you isolate your questions and separate them out of the specific body of code you are looking at, that's better--they can be triaged more easily as duplicates.

> What is the use of the constant INF?It isn’t used anywhere in the program. I understand that programmers very often leave some things in their programs which may not seem to be of any use presently, but would be useful for any future modifications. Does INF serve that same purpose? If any kind of modification is performed to make the program more efficient or to use a different method, INF is used?

If you delete the line declaring INF, does it still compile and work?  Does it get slower?  If so, it is a magic incantation that makes programs faster, known only in C++ secret societies.  :-)  If not, it's just a leftover definition as you suspect...perhaps used at some time, or perhaps never was.

See:

[How do I detect unused macro definitions & typedefs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16555863/how-do-i-detect-unused-macro-definitions-typedefs)

> The use of the left-shift operator inside the array dimensions. For example, int d[1<<20][20]. What purpose does the let-shift operator accomplish with regard to this program? There are various other instances where the let shift operator has been used inside array dimensions, and I can’t understand why.

In binary math, shifting 1 some number of bits left is the same as raising 2 to that power.  So `1 << 20` is `2^20`, or 1048576.  It's faster to bit shift than to call a power function, although with an optimized enough power function that can special case when the base is 2...how much faster may not be that much:

[are 2^n exponent calculations really less efficient than bit-shifts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12556906/are-2n-exponent-calculations-really-less-efficient-than-bit-shifts)

> The overloading of the less-than operator. In the Point structure, the less-than operator is overloaded. But I can’t seem to find out where in the program it has been called. It needs a Point object to call it, but I can’t find any place where any Point object calls that member function.

One might think that if you want to test if a method is ever called or a definition used, you can delete it and see if it still compiles.  But in C++ that doesn't *always* work; some definitions are overloads.  If you delete them, the program still compiles but just falls through to more basic behavior.  Even preprocessor macros can be funny because one file might detect if it had been defined elsewhere, and do something different if not...

There are other approaches, like just throwing an exception or asserting if it's ever called in the course of running.  People offer some other thoughts here:

[Find out if a function is called within a C++ project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1882070/find-out-if-a-function-is-called-within-a-c-project)

As @BrianSchlenker points out, the less than operator is definitely used despite the lack of explicit calls in the code shown.  It's used to order the elements of `map<Point,int> id;`.  The C++ `std::map` type imposes ordering on its contents, and defaults to using `operator<` to achieve this ordering...though you may override this.  If you print something out inside the less than function, you'll see it called every time the id map is interacted with.

*(Note: If you want an unordered map you have to use [std::unordered_map](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/unordered_map/), but that requires your datatype to have a different ability to calculate its `std::hash`...as well as a test for equality.)*

---

In general: this code is not stylized in a maintainable or readable manner.  I'd suggest that if you want to learn methods for increasing C++ program performance, you avoid the tarpit of reading any piece of obfuscated code you find...just because it happened to catch your attention.

Can you learn from it?  I guess, but de-obfuscating it and commenting it will be your first step.  Not a great idea, especially if you have to go asking others to help you do it, because even if they know how...they probably don't want to.  Better would be to work through steps to improve your own implementation in a stable logical way, where you don't step too far outside of your sphere of understanding in any one step.

*(Though if you can find the original author of such things, you might be able to engage them in a conversation about it and comment it for you.  If they don't have the interest, why would random people on the Internet?)*

Comment: The less than operator is definitely used. It's used to order the elements of the `map<Point,int>id;` map. If you print something out inside the less than function, you'll see it called every time the id map is interacted with.

Comment: @BrianSchlenker I didn't look too closely, or compile it, or test it with input...it was already a bit of unnecessary time spent on the answer.  :-)  But thanks for looking, editing...